# Understanding sharp quote in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp

In my experiments below I've abbreviated where the REPL returns an error, & added [num] so these can be referenced in discussion.

I'm a bit confused as to why my attempts to call a function stored in a variable are failing. It seems to me that the syntax is more complex than it needs to be.

Why can I issue neither `(f 3)` nor even `(#'f 3)`?
Is sharp quote not allowed as the first element of a form?
Why is `funcall` required here?

```lisp
[235]> (setf f #'abs)               ; I'm ok with this
#<SYSTEM-FUNCTION ABS>

[236]> (abs 3)                      ; This is fine
3

[237]> (f 3)                        ; Err due to sep. fn namespace. OK.
-- Err[1]: "Undefined function f" --

[238]> (#'f 3)                      ; Don't get what this err is telling me...
-- Err[2]: "#'F is not a function name, try using a symbol instead"

[239]> (funcall #'f 3)              ; seems very long winded...!
3
```

Does this mean system functions are treated differently from user defined functions?

For completeness:

```lisp
[240]> (funcall abs 3)
-- Err[3]: variable ABS has no value -- ; I get why this is an error.

[241]> (funcall #'abs 3)                ; Isn't this verbose... ?
3
```

I haven't got to the symbols chapter in ANSI Common Lisp yet, maybe that will help...  thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Function names have their own namespace**

We can set the function in the function namespace:

```
CL-USER 1 > (setf (fdefinition 'f) #'abs)
#<Function ABS 80E033E309>

CL-USER 2 > (f -42)
42
```

`FDEFINITION` gets the function object from a symbol naming a function. One can also use `SETF` to set the function.

**More examples**

```
[235]> (setf f #'abs)               ; I'm ok with this
#<SYSTEM-FUNCTION ABS>
```

Above kind of sets a variable named `f` to a function object - from the function called `abs`.

```
[236]> (abs 3)                      ; This is fine
3
```

Above called the function `abs`.

```
[237]> (f 3)                        ; Err due to sep. fn namespace. OK.
```

Above: there is no function named `f`.

```
-- Err[1]: "Undefined function f" --

[238]> (#'f 3)                      ; Don't get what this err is telling me...
-- Err[2]: "#'F is not a function name, try using a symbol instead"
```

Above: Common Lisp accepts only symbols as function names, symbols as macro names, symbols as special operators or lambda expressions as the first element of a cons form. `(function f)` is not a function name.

> Does this mean system functions are treated differently from user defined functions?

No.

```
[239]> (funcall #'f 3)              ; seems very long winded...!
3
```

Above calls the function `funcall` with the function object from the named function `f`. `funcall` then calls this function object with `3` as the argument.

> seems very long winded

It is.

> Why can I issue neither (f 3) nor even (#'f 3)? Is sharp quote not allowed as the first element of a form?

Because `f` is not naming a function. It names a variable. `#'f` is also not a function name. We are required to use a function name (a symbol actually).

**Namespaces**

Common Lisp (like some other Lisp dialects) has two namespaces for functions and for variables.

Defining a variable `foo`:

```
CL-USER 54 > (defvar foo 3)
FOO
```

Defining a function `foo`:

```
CL-USER 55 > (defun foo (x) (* foo 10))
FOO
```

We can call the function `foo` with the value obtained from the variable `foo`:

```
CL-USER 56 > (foo foo)
30
```

How to get the function object from the global name of the function:

```
CL-USER 57 > (fdefinition 'foo)
#<interpreted function FOO 4060001CAC>

CL-USER 58 > (symbol-function 'foo)
#<interpreted function FOO 4060001CAC>
```

Same as above, but with a short notation:

```
CL-USER 58a > #'foo
#<interpreted function FOO 4060001CAC>

CL-USER 59 > (function foo)            ; works also for local functions
#<interpreted function FOO 4230008AAC>
```

How to get a value from a global variable:

```
CL-USER 60 > (symbol-value 'foo)
3
```

Or just use the variable:

```
CL-USER 61 > foo
3
```

Some positives:

Positive: No name clashes.

We can write

```
(defun foo (list) (list list))
```

and don't have to write

```
(defun foo (lst) (list lst))
```

Positive: simpler compilation

```
(let ((list 3))
  (list 1 list 3))
```

Above will never be an error in Common Lisp. In Scheme it would be an error: `3 is not a function`.

Comment: Thanks - nice to hear the positives of having two namespaces. May I ask a follow up question? Was my use use of setf, as in `(setf f #'abs)`, which I now know assigns a function object to the _variable_ f (__not__ to the _function name_ f)", at all non-idiomatic?  Is "assigning to the (symbol as) function name f" only done with `defun`? (I see it is, alongside `flet` & `labels`) And that while I can if I wish assign a function to the _variable_ f, then if I do, I just have to accept the "long windedness" to which we refer?  ...onwards to the chapter on symbols... Thank you very much Rainer!

Comment: @mwal: The 'main' problem with `(setf f ...)` is that `f` is an undefined variable so far...

Comment: @mwal: you can set a variable to a function, but we would need a reason for it...